# Correct header for python UTF-8 script in v2.7 and v3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I've found many answers for different versions of python but I'll love some insights about any "best practices" method of both allowing UTF-8 characters in code & commentd and in input recieved values.

If this could or should change for the same script in different plattforms (win, mac, etc).

For a time now I've been using this header in my scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This prevents encoding errors from showing when I use UTF-8 chars in my code and comments.

The `/usr/bin/env` part has no meaning to me in a windows box. I supose just exists for nix boxes?

Sorry if this question is too basic, but I need a simple answer, not a much technical one.

In my sad windows 7 world I also have to use (in Py27 only) something like this just below the heades to read properly a `chcp 1252` terminal input:

```
import codecs,locale,sys
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout)
```

I know this should be another question, but both things are connected so...

Is there a "magical UTF-8 headerset" that could work on win/mac/nix without changes? Is that only posible in py3?

Thanks.

Comment: Which text editor are you using?

Comment: Mostly Sublime and some times Spyder

Comment: source file encoding has nothing to do with "*to read properly a ... terminal input". One tell python how to interpret the python code (and python will transform anyway the string in own internal representation). Output depends on the local computer, not on developer environment, so python uses them as separate issues.

Comment: Redefining `sys.stdout` doesn't change how terminal input is read. It is only about output.